# Finding g[f(x,y,z)] vector calculus

Tags: calculus, vectors

I'm not sure how to calculate this:

If $g(t)=t^3$ and $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2z$, what is $g[f(1,1,3)]$?

Comment: Can you calculate $f(1,1,3)$?

Comment: $g[f(1,1,3)]=(f(1,1,3))^3$.

Comment: wow, i feel dumb.  thank you

Answer (score 1):

$f(1,1,3) = 1^2 + 1^2*3 = 4$

$g(4) = 4^3 = 64$